# TCP Server - Recover from "Too many open files"

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a TCP server in C and find something unusual happens once the listening fd get "Too many open files" error. The `accept` call doesn't block anymore and returns -1 all the time.

I also tried closing the listening fd and re-opening, re-binding it, but didn't seem to work.

My questions are why `accept` keeps returning -1 in this situation, what am I supposed to do to stop it <s>and make the server be able to accept new connections after any old clients closed</s>? (the socket is of course able to `accept` correctly again when some connections closed)

====== UPDATE: clarification ======

The problem occurs just because the number of active clients is more than the limit of open fds, so I don't `close` any of the accepted fds in the sample code, just to make it reproduce more quickly.

I add the timestamp each time `accept` returns to the output and slow down `connect` frequency to once in 2 seconds, then I find that in fact the "Too many open files" error occurs immediately after the lastest success `accept`. So I think that is because when the maxium fds is reached, each call to `accept` will return immediately, and the return value is -1. (What I thought is that `accept` would still block, but returns -1 at the next incoming `connect`. The behavior of `accept` in this situation is my own theory, not from the man page. If it's wrong, please let me know).

So to my second question, to make it stop, I think it's a solution that stop to call `accept` before any connection is `close`d.

Also update the sample codes. Thanks for your help.

====== Sample codes ======

Here is how I test it. First set `ulimit -n` to a low value (like 16) and run the server program compiled from the following C source; then use the Python script to create several connections

```
/* TCP server; bind :5555 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define PORT 5555

void error(char const* msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int listen_port(int port)
{
    int parentfd; /* parent socket */
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr; /* server's addr */
    int optval; /* flag value for setsockopt */
    parentfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (parentfd < 0) {
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    }

    optval = 1;
    setsockopt(parentfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 
           (const void *)&optval , sizeof(int));

    bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));

    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);

    if (bind(parentfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0) {
        error("ERROR on binding");
    }

    if (listen(parentfd, 5) < 0) {
        error("ERROR on listen");
    }
    printf("Listen :%d\n", port);
    return parentfd;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int parentfd; /* parent socket */
    int childfd; /* child socket */
    int clientlen; /* byte size of client's address */
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr; /* client addr */
    int accept_count; /* times of accept called */

    accept_count = 0;
    parentfd = listen_port(PORT);

    clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);

    while (1) {
        childfd = accept(parentfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, (socklen_t*) &clientlen);
        printf("accept returns ; count=%d ; time=%u ; fd=%d\n", accept_count++, (unsigned) time(NULL), childfd);
        if (childfd < 0) {
            perror("error on accept");

            /* the following 2 lines try to close the listening fd and re-open it */
            // close(parentfd);
            // parentfd = listen_port(PORT);

            // the following line let the program exit at the first error
            error("--- error on accept");
        }
    }
}
```

The Python program to create connections

```
import time
import socket

def connect(host, port):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socks = []

    try:
        try:
            for i in xrange(100):
                socks.append(connect('127.0.0.1', 5555))
                print ('connect count: ' + str(i))
                time.sleep(2)
        except IOError as e:
            print ('error: ' + str(e))
        print ('stop')
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for s in socks:
            s.close()
```

Comment: I notices your sample code doesn't deal with the client at all. In a comment you stated that this was for readability... but this might hide the issue as well. For example, if your calling `fork`, you need to remember to close the connection on **all** processes (the connection is duplicated and closed only when all open handles are closed). Issues such as these can't be reviewed using your sample code. For now, you just need to call `close` on the client, as stated by others before me.

Answer (score 3):

> why accept keeps returning -1 in this situation

Because you've run out of file descriptors, just like the error message says.

> what am I supposed to do to stop it and make the server be able to accept new connections after any old clients closed?

Close the clients. The *problem* is not `accept()` returning -1, it is that you aren't closing accepted sockets once you're finished with them.

Closing the listening socket isn't a solution. It's just another problem.

**EDIT** By 'finished with them' I mean one of several things:

1. They have finished with you, which is shown by `recv()` returning zero.
2. You have finished with them, e.g. after sending a final response.
3. When you've had an error sending or receiving to/from them other than EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.
4. When you've had some other internal fatal error that prevents you dealing further with that client, for example receiving an unparseable request, or some other fatal application error that invalidates the connection or the session, or the entire client for that matter.

In all these cases you should close the accepted socket.

Comment: I just remove the `close` calls from the sample code because in this situation the current clients may be still active. Could you tell me what should I do to at least stop the `accept` from returning -1?

Comment: I've already told you. Close accepted sockets once you've finished with them.

Comment: @neuront Well when are you going to be finished with the child FDs? Whenever that is, when it happens, you need to close them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I made a further clarification about why I'm not going to `close`. And I might misunderstand the behavior of `accept`. I'm appreciated if you could take a look at it.

Comment: If your objective is to establish how many live connections you can handle at once, you've found it. If your objective is not to get -1 returns from `accept()`, you have to close client sockets when you are finished with them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of EJP is correct, but it does not tell you how to deal with the situation. What you have to do is actually do something with the sockets that you get as accept returns. Simple calling close on them you won't receive anything of course but it would deal with the resource depletion problem. What you have to do to have a correct implementation is start receiving on the accepted sockets and keep receiving until you receive 0 bytes. If you receive 0 bytes, that is an indication that the peer is done using his side of the socket. That is your trigger to call close on the socket as well and deal with the resource problem.

You don't have to stop listening. That would stop your server from being able to process new requests and that is not the problem here.

Comment: That's when *they* are finished with *you.* There are other occasions to close the socket. *You* can be finished with *them* (e.g. keepalive timeout, or single-shot connection), or you could have incurred a fatal error handling that client.

Comment: The OP does not really give a clue about that so I was assuming that he was going to send data towards the server. Anyway receiving and watching out for 0 received bytes is key to the solution here. And top of this lots of error cases. As you have now mentioned in your updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I implemented [here](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools/blob/c1888deb937f1290b66432bd5b04573b25501187/src/lib-server.c#L759-L767) was to review the value of the new (accepted) `fd` and if that value was equal or higher then the allowed server capacity, then a "busy" message is sent and the new connection is closed.

This solution is quite effective and allows you to inform your clients about the server's status.